# Trigger build from bitbucket to Jenkins based on Tags (Declarative Syntax)

Tags: linux, git, jenkins

I am looking for a help in Jenkins to trigger a build when specific tags(release.*) are pushed.

So far I got the way of skipping the deployment if there are no proper tags (https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/05/16/pipelines-with-git-tags/)

```
   stage('Deploy') {
            when { tag "release-*" }
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying only because this commit is tagged...'
                sh 'make deploy'
            }
        }
```

Looks for something which will help me to trigger the builds from feature branch whenever a developer will push a tag.